# Are people in combinatorics distinguishable or indistinguishable?

Tags: combinatorics

It seems that sometimes they are distinguishable and other times they are indistinguishable! Why would this happen? When would you know whether people are distinguishable or indistinguishable?

I guess since people are all different and cant be "replaced", they are distinguishable. Is it just a definition that varies from different syllabuses/countries?

Comment: "When would you know whether people are distinguishable or indistinguishable".  The specific combinatorics problem that asks you to enumerate different collections of people **must explicitly specify** whether the people are to be considered distinguishable or not.  Otherwise, any such problem will be **ambiguous.**  For example, consider the problem "How many ways are there for 3 people to occupy no more than 2 rooms, where each person goes to one of the two rooms"?  You will get one answer if the people are distinguishable and a different answer if they are not distinguishable.

Comment: There is one way to line $5$ indistinguishable people but $5!$ ways to line $5$ distinguishable people. In reality, people are all distinguishable so questions involving permutation and combination of people will usually not state that the people are distinguishable as it is implicitly assumed.

Comment: I can't remember coming across a problem where it was explicitly stated that people are indistinguishable , but sometimes the problem isn't about individuals but classes of people, e.g. women/men. Also, if probability is to be computed, distinguishability generally doesn't matter

Comment: Ahhh I see. Thanks for the comments guys. @true blue anil 's statement was where my confusion came from. I saw a question regarding the arrangement of *students*. How should I know if they are distinguishable or not? Students would count as a "class" I guess.

Comment: The question should tell you if the order of the students matters. However, in case it doesn't tell you, if the question is asking about the number of possible ways to arrange students, like in a seating arrangement, unless there's some distinction between groups of students I would work under the assumption that the students are distinguishable, or in other words that the order does matter. However that is just a guess, and whether or not it's even a sensible one depends on the details your problem.